# A simple visual association puzzle

Tags: knowledge, visual

This is not image steganography, I am going to show you six images, the images seem to be unrelated to each other, but they are all in fact related to some aspect of a hypothetical scenario, they revolve around a central theme, your task is to identify the theme and explain why each image is chosen.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This one was a little too obvious, but I like the idea.

Comment: Please stop downvoting this post, it was meant to be obvious, you know I can't delete this question unless the answer is deleted first.

Comment: Anyways if you want this post to disappear, bug some moderators or bug the answerer, don't cast anymore downvotes, it is beyond my power to delete this post, if you want this post deleted, I am more than happy to consent, since I don't see anyone upvoting it in the forseeable future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These all seem to have to do with

> Nuclear war/disaster

The mushroom

> suggests a [mushroom cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushroom_cloud)

DO NOT PRESS

> The big red button that launches the nukes.

Volcano

> explosion

Ferris wheel

> @Bass recognized this is the abandoned [Pripyat amusement park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pripyat_amusement_park), a symbol of the Chernobyl disaster.

Clock

> The [Doomsday Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_Clock) that counts down to a nuclear war.

Atom

> Uranium used in nuclear bombs.

Comment: The ferris wheel looks a lot like the one in [Pripyat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pripyat_amusement_park).